# What is the name of a doctrine that aims to solidify state loyalty by allowing minorities to secede?

Tags: political-theory, terminology, ideology, nationalism

Is there a name for a doctrine that states that a nation state would be better off by allowing minorities, such as the Arabs in Israel, Kurds in Turkey, or Albanians in Macedonia, to actually secede in order to get a sustainable percentage of the majority ethnic group to solidify loyalty to the state/identity?

Mainstream nationalism usually does the opposite, that is, it puts territorial aspirations above homogeneity of population and often seeks to suppress minority nationalism. I am looking whether there is a name for the above described strategy of national unity and maybe some historical examples.

Please note I am looking only for the name, if exists, and not for opinions on moral correctness or political feasibility.

Comment: might be worth looking at the Czechoslovakia => Czech Republic, Slovakia split and see what terms/political theories were being used/referred to, because it does seem to be an instance of just what you are asking about.

Comment: I think the term "demographic engineering" may apply. [What is “demographic engineering” and how does it differ from ethnic cleansing?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/what-is-demographic-engineering-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ethnic-cleansing/46362#46362).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this wholly fits your request, but [the Doctrine of remedial secession](https://loyalnigerianlawyer.com/remedial-secession-in-international-law-understanding-the-legal-status-of-a-seperatist-group-by-fredrick-okagua/) seems to be close:

> Remedial Secession proponents pinpoint certain institutional practice,
>   States practice and Opinion Juris of the state that reflect the
>   existence of right to remedial secession as lex lata norm.

Quebec is mentioned as an example:

> In the Quebec case, the Supreme Court of Canada adopted a conservative
>   construction of **“external self-determination”** as a right that may be
>   exercised under limited conditions only. Thus, no precedent for a
>   right to secede was established in judicial practice. Though,
>   exceptions to this neutrality may arise from the interplay of the
>   principles of territorial integrity and self-determination.